# Массив и условие. Что не так?

Tags: php

Прошу, помогите. Есть такой код:

```
for ($x = $nach; $x <$end; $x++)
{
echo $buf2 = $arr_res[$i][2];
echo '<br>';
if ($buf2 = $x)
{
echo $x.' '.$buf2.' ';
}
}
echo '<br>';
```

$nach =9; $end =17;
$arr_res[$i][2] - либо 10, либо 12
Почему я получаю следующее?

```
10
9 9 10
10 10 10
11 11 10
12 12 10
13 13 10
14 14 10
15 15 10
16 16
12
9 9 12
10 10 12
11 11 12
12 12 12
13 13 12
14 14 12
15 15 12
16 16
```

То бишь с какого `$buf2` приравнивается к `$x`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$buf2 = $x` - операция присваивания

`$buf2 == $x` и `$buf2 === $x` - операции сравнения